# Sort a structure by one of its elements

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sorting, struct

I have this structure:

```
Structure Candidat
    Public Nume As String
    Public Scoala As String
    Public Localitatea As String
    Public Optiuni As String
    Public Nota1 As Integer
    Public Nota2 As Integer
End Structure

Public cd(100) As Candidat
```

I need to print the elements of the structure in a txt file, but ordered by name (by cd.Nume)

```
For i = 0 to some_number
    PrintLine(1, cd(i).Nume, TAB(20), cd(i).Scoala, TAB(40), cd(i).Localitatea, TAB(60), cd(i).Optiuni, TAB(80), cd(i).Nota1, TAB(90), cd(i).Nota2)
Next
```

I saw something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751768/sort-an-array-of-structures-in-net) but I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `vb.net` as the programming language.

From the post you reference - the accepted answer is (by @Fredrik Mörk):

"

*Assuming that the structure has a property called MPH:*

*`cars = cars.OrderBy(Function(c) c.MPH)`*

*Note: the above code was auto-converted from the following c# code (in case it contains errors):*

*`cars = cars.OrderBy(c => c.MPH);`*

"

so you'll need to call
`cd = cd.OrderBy(c => c.Nume);` right before the printing `for` loop.