# Sorting an Structured object

Tags: vb.net, sorting

Sorting:

```
    Dim objReport(0) As stReport
    Try
        For intK = 1 To 15
            objReport(intK).Name = "User" & GetRandomNumber()
            objReport(intK).Age = intK
            objReport(intK).Misc1 = "data"
        Next

        Return objReport
```

Is there any simple way to sort the objReport order by Name?

NOTE: The code is just a sample.

Comment: dim orderedList = From r in objReport Order by r.Name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an array of structures in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751768/sort-an-array-of-structures-in-net)

Comment: Hi @Jeremy How to reassign the result to the same object                     i.e need to reassign to objReport

Comment: @JamesThorpe you are named for a town in Pennsylvania :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Thorpe,_Pennsylvania

Comment: @Jeremy Which itself is named after a former athlete I believe - I've heard of him before :)  Alas, "Thorpe" is fairly common over here in the UK originally meaning a small village or hamlet.  I myself grew up in Edenthorpe, with Armthorpe and Scunthorpe amongst others nearby :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort them using `OrderBy` Extension Function

```
objReport = objReport.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Name).ToArray()
```