# VB.NET - How to sort a structure array using quicksort for different fields?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, structure, quicksort

Ive created a quicksort for sorting a structure array by a certain field. But to sort by every field I would have to have n * quicksorts, where n is the number of fields in a structure. At the moment its 12... Ive been trying to lower it to just 1 quicksort. I explain in more detail below.

I have a structure called InformationAboutJob, it has 12 fields:

```
 Public Structure InformationAboutJob
        Public DatabaseID As Integer
        Public Title As String
        Public DateOfJob As Date
        Public StartTime As String
        Public EndTime As String
        Public Location As String
        Public Specials As String
        Public Note As String
        Public IndividualIncome As String
        Public Income As String
        Public TeamSize As String
        Public Status As String
    End Structure
```

Then I have an array of that structure, the size is determined in a different sub:

```
Public Shared InfoJobs() As InformationAboutJob
```

I have a sub-procedure to fill this array of structures from a database.

But once it is filled, I need to sort it by ascending/descending order.
I have a quicksort which sorts it in ascending order (A to Z in my case) and then for descending I think I can just do InfoJobs.Reverse but a descending order does not matter at the moment.

This is the quicksort:

```
   Private Sub QuickSortFilter(StartIndex As Integer, EndIndex As Integer)
        'Setting the lowest and highest pointers to work with
        Dim LowestIntegerPointer As Integer = StartIndex
        Dim HighestIntegerPointer As Integer = EndIndex
        'Finding the middle of the array
        Dim MiddlePointer As String = InfoJobs((LowestIntegerPointer + HighestIntegerPointer) / 2).Title.ToLower
        Dim Temp As InformationAboutJob

        Do Until LowestIntegerPointer > HighestIntegerPointer
            Do While InfoJobs(LowestIntegerPointer).Title.ToLower < MiddlePointer
                LowestIntegerPointer += 1
            Loop
            Do While MiddlePointer < InfoJobs(HighestIntegerPointer).Title.ToLower
                HighestIntegerPointer -= 1
            Loop
            If LowestIntegerPointer <= HighestIntegerPointer Then
                Temp = InfoJobs(LowestIntegerPointer)
                InfoJobs(LowestIntegerPointer) = InfoJobs(HighestIntegerPointer)
                InfoJobs(HighestIntegerPointer) = Temp
                LowestIntegerPointer += 1
                HighestIntegerPointer -= 1
            End If
        Loop
        If StartIndex < HighestIntegerPointer Then QuickSortFilter(StartIndex, HighestIntegerPointer)
        If LowestIntegerPointer < EndIndex Then QuickSortFilter(LowestIntegerPointer, EndIndex)
    End Sub
```

The *.ToLower* function is used because strings are compared by ASCII values I think and capitals have a higher ASCII value than lower so I make them all the same (lower case)

The quicksort works but only for InfoJobs(x).Title. I am trying to make it work so I can maybe pass in a field that I want it to sort by so I can call it like this:

Original: `QuickSortFilter(0, InfoJobs.Length - 1)`

Desired: `QuickSortFilter(0, InfoJobs.Length -1, Title)`

*Title* being a field just like *DateOfJob* etc.

I have searched and searched but found no solution, so I ask for your help.
Thank you for reading.

Note: I only replaced the bubble sort with a quicksort because its quicker (surprisingly :D), an example of recursion and the bubble sort was a very long and slow case statement.

The answer I adopted:

```
Dim orderByResult As IEnumerable(Of InformationAboutJob)
orderByResult = From s In InfoJobs
                Order By s.Title
                Select s

Dim Counter As Integer = 0
For Each job As InformationAboutJob In orderByResult
         InfoJobs(Counter) = job
         Counter += 1
Next
```

Follow this article to understand the above code if you are struggling:
[LINQ OrderBy](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-sorting-operators-orderby-orderbydescending)

I only modified the output, where it was printing to the console from *orderByResult* I just set it to replace the old array (*InfoJobs()*) with the new sorted values from *orderByResult*.

Comment: You should check whether such sort is not already in .NET framework.

Comment: I checked and found a comparer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx. The second example looks similar to the problem but I dont know how to make it work for my example... Im new

Comment: Ok, do you know LINQ OrderBy, ThenBy ?

Comment: @Arek Maslany If this is not an exercise in sorting, you could use the already existing [Array.Sort()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx) method (it uses quicksort too). You can use one of the default IComparer or define one of your own. Add some knowledge in Lambda expressions too.

Comment: I dont think I can use that for my structure, I tried something very similar or the same earlier and I couldnt get it to work. Also, I implemented a quicksort because this is a school project and we got advised to implement a sort

Comment: @Aybe, I am trying LINQ OrderBy now it looks like it might work.

Comment: @Jimi, I struggled to understand how I could implement the IComparer because on MSDN they make it a class and add properties. I will try it if LINQ OrderBy does not work

Comment: @Arek Maslany  It's a common task, ordering Lists, Arrays. You will find many examples using different tools. For example: [Sort an array of structures in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751768/sort-an-array-of-structures-in-net)

Comment: LINQ OrderBy almost worked, it sorted it but I need to see how to manipulate the output to display how I want it.

Comment: We have a winner! Thank you everyone. LINQ OrderBy worked. I will also try and implement the other solutions as well as it would be good to know them. Thank you for the help :-)

Comment: Good, you should be able to cover most cases by chaining LINQ method calls, eventually implement your own comparer for a custom sort (the API is good enough so that you can manipulate it through this way).